# Sending search request to Datatables jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Has anyone ever sent a search request from one page to the dataTables jquery plugin on another page?
I'm not sure if its even designed to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is what you are looking for:**

```
$('#dataTableBLOCK').dataTable( {
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": "YOUR-SEARCH-VALUE"},
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "NAME-OF-DATATABLES-FILE.php"
} );
```

By changing `YOUR-SEARCH-VALUE` to a `$_POST` or `$_GET` value you make dataTables search what you were searching somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure that the search will only work when you are in the same page.  The search box will filter the displayed rows of the table when the dataTables plugin is used.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm rather hoping that you can send the search parameter to the page that contains dataTables.